# Complete rings and modules(topologically)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

In the a-adic topology, if M,N are A-modules, and N is the homomorphic image of M, can we prove that N is complete whenever M is? in other words, does completeness carries over to homomorphic images.

Comment: This is clear if $A$ is Noetherian and $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated, so presumably you are thinking of some more general context.  Are you willing to assume any finiteness conditions at all?
